# in input onchange event, update array inside the component

Tags: angular, rxjs, angular8

I'm starting to learn angular right now, and trying to understand the concept of an Observable and how to use them.

I've read all that there is about them in the angular documentation, but I'm either not understanding the concept correctly, or if just not possible.

I'll explain my idea:

I have an input element:

```
<div class="response" *ngFor="let reply of currentResponse.replies">
    <input style="word-break: break-all;" type="text" placeholder="Message" value="{{ reply.text }}"/>
</div>
```

and in the component as a property:

```
fileData: ResponseModel[];
// and
currentResponse: ResponseModel
```

ResponseModel as context:

```
class ResponseModel {
    constructor(
        public id: string,
        public replies: Array<Reply>,
        public suggestedActions: [],
        public inputHint: string
    ) {}
}
```

My idea:

could it be possible to attach the `onchange` event of the input to the `fileData` array or the `currentResponse` property, so that when a value changes in the input, the value will change in the array.

And then, when a value changes in the `fileData` array, update the service that is populating it.

Or If I've misunderstood the use of Observable.

Thanks,
Nestor

Comment: what does this have to do with observables?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use angular two ways binding [(ngModel)]:

```
<input [(ngModel)]="yourVariableName"><input>
```

The variable should be a string type. So Input is related to that variable, whenever you change that variable the text inside input will update and vice-versa(when you write inside input will update the variable).

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The array contains references to the objects.when you bind the array item to value `value="{{ reply.text }}"` the references of `currentResponse.replies` is attached to this.so when you update the value of input box it automatically update the array.